# Read variables from a file and store them in structs - C

Tags: c, struct, io

I'm having some serious trouble with this program.
Pretty much I need to read from a file that has a set of first and last name, a cookie type, the amount purchased, the cost, and whether is was paid for or not.

I'm fairly confident that my functions are correct.

When I run the program, it runs correctly but there looks to be extra digits in between certain numbers. What I mean is, if the input file is:
John Green mint 1 1.00 Y
Jane Blue chip 2 2.00 N
The output file will be something like:
John Green 12 20000 mint 455 1 etc...

Any ideas? I'm guessing I messed up in reading the file/storing them into the struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*structure definition*/
struct customer{
    char first[12], last[12], type[10], paid;
    int boxes;
    float cost;
};

/*prototypes*/
void readCustomerData(FILE*, struct customer[]);
void printCustomerData(FILE*, int, struct customer[]);
float moneyReceived(int, struct customer[]);
int custWhoOwe(int, struct customer[]);
float moneyOutstanding(int, struct customer[]);
int moneyReceivedPercent(int, struct customer[]);

int main (){ 
    int numCustomers;
    float money, money2;
    int cust, perc;
    FILE*input;
    FILE*output;

    input = fopen("custInfo.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    fscanf(input, "%d", &numCustomers);


    struct customer customerData[numCustomers];

    readCustomerData(input, customerData);
    printCustomerData(output, numCustomers, customerData);
    fprintf(output, "Summary:\n\n");
    money = moneyReceived(numCustomers, customerData);
    fprintf(output, "Total Cash Received: $%.2f\n\n", money);
    cust = custWhoOwe(numCustomers, customerData);
    fprintf(output, "Num customers who have not paid: %d\n\n", cust);
    money2 = moneyOutstanding(numCustomers, customerData);
    fprintf(output, "Total Amount Outstanding: $%.2f\n\n", money2);
    perc = moneyReceivedPercent(numCustomers, customerData);
    fprintf(output, "Percentage of Sales outstanding: %d%%\n\n", perc);



    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}

void readCustomerData(FILE*file, struct customer cdata[]){
    int numCustomers, i;
    file = fopen("custInfo.txt", "r");

    fscanf(file, "%d", &numCustomers);

    for (i=0; i<numCustomers; i++){
        fscanf(file, "%s%s%s%d%f%c", &cdata[i].first, &cdata[i].last, &cdata[i].type, &cdata[i].boxes, &cdata[i].cost, &cdata[i].paid);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void printCustomerData(FILE*file, int num, struct customer cdata[]){
    int i;
    fprintf(file, "Customers:\n\n");
    fprintf(file, "Name\t\tType of Cookie\t\tNum of Boxes\tCost of Box\tPaid\n");
    fprintf(file, "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    for (i=0; i<num; i++){
    fprintf(file, "%s %s\t", cdata[i].first, cdata[i].last);
    fprintf(file, "%s\t\t", cdata[i].type);
    fprintf(file, "%d\t\t", cdata[i].boxes);
    fprintf(file, "$%.2f\t\t", cdata[i].cost);
    fprintf(file, "%c", cdata[i].paid);
    fprintf(file, "\n\n");
}
    fprintf(file, "\n\n\n\n\n");

}

float moneyReceived(int num, struct customer cdata[]){
    int i, sum=0;
    for (i=0; i<num; i++){
        if(cdata[i].paid=='Y'){
            sum= sum+(cdata[i].cost*cdata[i].boxes);}
}
    return sum;
}

int custWhoOwe(int num, struct customer cdata[]){
    int count=0, i;
    for (i=0; i<num; i++){
        if (cdata[i].paid=='N'){
            count++;}
    }
    return count;
}

float moneyOutstanding(int num, struct customer cdata[]){
    int i, sum=0;
    for (i=0; i<num; i++){
        if (cdata[i].paid=='N'){
            sum= sum+(cdata[i].cost*cdata[i].boxes);}
    }
    return sum;
}

int moneyReceivedPercent(int num, struct customer cdata[]){
    int answ;
    float money, moneyOut;
    money = moneyReceived(num, cdata);
    moneyOut = moneyOutstanding(num, cdata);

    answ=(moneyOut/money)*100;

    return answ;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%s%s%s%d%f%c",` --> `fscanf(file, "%s%s%s%d%f %c",`  Add space before %c

Comment: Sweet mother of God you're amazing thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier.  C11 §7.21.6.2 8

1) Add a space before `"%c"` to consume white-space.  `"%c"` does not do it by itself.  The other used specifiers do that even without a leading space.

2) Check the return value of `*scanf()` functions.  Unless the return value if 6, in this case, do not trust that the scan completed successfully.

3) Limit string input by declaring a width one less than the size for `'%s'`.  Code certainly should be prevented from overrunning the arrays.

```
for (i=0; i<numCustomers; i++){
  // fscanf(file, "%s%s%s%d%f%c", &cdata[i].first, &cdata[i].last, 
  //   &cdata[i].type, &cdata[i].boxes, &cdata[i].cost, &cdata[i].paid);

  if (6 != fscanf(file, "%11s%11s%9s%d%f %c", 
      &cdata[i].first, &cdata[i].last, &cdata[i].type, 
      &cdata[i].boxes, &cdata[i].cost, &cdata[i].paid)) {
    printf("Bad input!");
  }
}
```